# What does the tag attribute in Reactstrap do?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I have a navbar using reactstrap and wanted to incorporate react-router.
After a failed attempt I have found the solution here.

However I don't understand the syntax:

I have a `<NavLink>` from React-Router
and a navbar from Reactstrap.

Instead of wrapping the Reactstrap's  inside React-Router's  (Which throws a warning):

```
 <NavLink to="/">
   <NavbarBrand className="mx-auto" to="/" tag={ NavLink }>
      My Site
   </NavbarBrand>
 </NavLink>
```

This is the syntax:

```
   <NavbarBrand className="mx-auto" to="/" tag={ NavLink }>
      My Site
   </NavbarBrand>
```

What is the **tag** attribute? What does it do?

Thanks all!

Comment: It's a prop that NavBarBrand takes. Did you check documentation/source code?

Answer (score 3):

When you render `NavbarBrand` component you have an option to render individual links as default `a` tag (HTMLAnchorElement) or you can provide your own custom component to render navigation items.

In this case it's convenient to pass `NavLink` as a tag so that nav items are rendered with `NavLink`. This is what you need.

Looking into respectful [source code for `NavbarBrand`](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/9f7b741f5c85810afc92c9e2488628996a7a0e26/src/NavbarBrand.js#L30) you see this in render method:

```
return (
  <Tag {...attributes} className={classes} />
);
```

So if you don't pass `tag` prop to `NavbarBrand` then above `Tag` is going to be [`a` tag](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/9f7b741f5c85810afc92c9e2488628996a7a0e26/src/NavbarBrand.js#L13).

Comment: So this isn't a react thing? It's just a prop of the navbar components in Reactstrap?

Comment: @DM Yes, this is just usual custom prop.

Answer (score 0):

The docs aren't hugely clear on this, but all can be revealed by looking at [the source](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/NavbarBrand.js):

```
const NavbarBrand = (props) => {
  const {
    className,
    cssModule,
    tag: Tag,
    ...attributes
  } = props;

  const classes = mapToCssModules(classNames(
    className,
    'navbar-brand'
  ), cssModule);

  return (
    <Tag {...attributes} className={classes} />
  );
};
```

`NavbarBrand` effectively just instantiates whatever tag/component you give it with the appropriate style classes applied, and passes the rest of the props on to it.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the documentation and there was no description of what `tag` does, but `PropTypes` validate whether it is a `string` or a `function`

My reasoning [based on examples](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/breadcrumbs/) is this:

```
  <Breadcrumb tag="nav">
    <BreadcrumbItem tag="a" href="#">Home</BreadcrumbItem>
    <BreadcrumbItem tag="a" href="#">Library</BreadcrumbItem>
    <BreadcrumbItem tag="a" href="#">Data</BreadcrumbItem>
    <BreadcrumbItem active tag="span">Bootstrap</BreadcrumbItem>
  </Breadcrumb>
```

it accepts the name of an HTML tag or a React Component to be used as a wrapper.